# SQL , getting invalid column name error for a piece of code working perfectly online

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This is my table : [image]

I am taking an online course on Udemy in SQL, the video has this code and it is running. I do not know why I get error below when I run it. I appreciate any help.
the code is supposed to return the number of each age group in each region.

```
select * from dbo.tblCustomer;
select Region,   
       case when Age>54 then 'old'
            when Age<36 then 'young'
            else 'mid' end as age_group
        ,count(*) as freq
from dbo.tblCustomer 
group by Region, age_group
order by Region, freq desc;
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 43 
> Invalid column name 'age_group'.
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
> Invalid column name 'count'.

PS. I took $9.9 courses on Udemy, this is a screen shot of the video I'm learning SQL from. his codes, mine does not. Now with help wonderful StackOverflow people I am learning why. I spent three hours to google here and there and try to study W3Schools for this.

[image]

Comment: *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, **Line 43**
Invalid column name 'age_group'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, **Line 44**
Invalid column name 'count'.* Please provide real and complete code.

Comment: PS. Tags list corrected (MySQL removed, SQL Server added).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @ Akina, I assume you mean why these are lines 43 , 44 and not like 1,2 ?? simply because I m practicing, so there are other examples in a sheet . that simple. thank you anyway.

Comment: @Mathica you will struggle if your teaching materials are related to a different database engine. Each engine has its own SQL dialect which supports different syntax and features. If you intend to use sql server, then find a course based on that engine (and version).

Comment: The reason why is that your course is running PostgreSQL whereas you are running SQL Server - they are two completely different RDBMSs and as such work differently. Each RDBMS implements SQL in its own unique way.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that :(

Comment: *try to study W3Schools* - no, the internet has a wealth of good resource, I would avoid that particular one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your case expression query up in a derived table. GROUP BY its result:

```
select Region, age_group, count(*) freq
from
(
    select Region,   
           case when Age>54 then 'old'
                when Age<36 then 'young'
                else 'mid' end as age_group
    from dbo.tblCustomer 
) dt
group by Region, age_group
order by Region, freq desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same query in the way you are doing due to the order of execution.

You either need to repeat the expression in the group-by or you can use a CTE or Derived Table, where you can then reference them. You should also be able to materialize your case expression using *apply*:

```
select Region, age_group, Count(*) as freq
from dbo.tblCustomer 
cross apply(
    values(
        case when Age>54 then 'old'
             when Age<36 then 'young'
             else 'mid'
        end
    )
)v(age_group)
group by Region, age_group
order by Region, Count(*) desc;
```